# file.delete is not working in android studio

Tags: android-studio, delete-file

I have the delete button which is supposed to delete the selected files in adapter class. But it is not working at all nothing happens when the button is clicked. I don't understand what is the problem. Here is the implementation

```
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                            int id = item.getItemId();

                            switch (id) {
                                case R.id.delete:
                                    for (ItemFiles v : selectList) {
                                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + String.valueOf(v));
                                        if (file.exists()) {
                                            file.delete();
                                        }
```

v is selected file/s which are to be deleted. There is a warning on file.delete that say "Result of 'File.delete()' is ignored". Any suggestion would be helpful Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot File.separator

```
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                        int id = item.getItemId();
                        switch (id) {
                            case R.id.delete:
                                for (ItemFiles v : selectList) {
                                    File file = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator 
+ String.valueOf(v));
                                    if (file.exists()) {
                                        file.delete();
                                    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but it behaves the same way and warning is still there.